# Output numbers for `git log`

Tags: git

I'm doing:

`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -10`

which outputs:

```
sha1 <pretty format>
sha1 <pretty format>
```

and I'd like each line to start with an incrementing number. E.g.

```
1. sha1 <pretty format>
2. sha1 <pretty format>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -10 | cat -n`

Or:

`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -10 | nl`

Or if you really want the `.`:

`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -10 | nl -s'. '`

(With the caveat that `nl` pads the numbers.)

(And of course a million different `sed` and `awk` solutions.)